# How to check union type belongs to one of the interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have a type alias that is a union of two interfaces:

`type selectedMarket = IPositionListItem | IMarket`

```
interface IPositionListItem {
  base: number;
  counter: number;
  title: string;
  name: string;
  priceAgo: number;
  price: string;
  change: number;
}


interface IMarket {
  base: number;
  counter: number;
  name: string;
  spot_name: string;
  start: number;
  expires: number;
  tenor: string;
  tick: number;
}
```

I want to call `selectedMarket.price`, but it's throwing an error because `IMarket` doesn't contain `price` as one of its properties. How can I check that `selectedMarket` is of type `IPositionListItem`? `typeof` and `instanceof` don't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link can help you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types. Here is used `as` to cast the instance.

```
if( (selectedMarket as IMarket).tick) {
   (selectedMarket as IMarket).tick
} else {
   ...
}
```